# How to broadcast messages to all clients using tcp in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

I am building a multithreaded chat server application which broadcasts a message sent by one client to all the clients.On most of the examples on internet and on **Oracle's website** too broadcasting is done using udp (Multicast Socket)but i am using tcp .
Does anyone know how to send a message to all the connected clients in a tcp conection?
Here is my current code which works fine and sends the message receieved from a client to that client only:

**EchoServer**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EchoServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java EchoServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread t = new Thread(new MultiServer(serverSocket.accept()));
                t.start();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Accept Failed:");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EchoClient**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java EchoClient <host name><portnumber>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String hostName = "localhost";

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try (
            Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ) {
            String userInput;

            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null)  {
                out.println(userInput);
                System.out.println("echo::" + in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } 
    }
}
```

**MultiServer**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MultiServer implements Runnable
{
    private Socket client;

    public MultiServer(Socket m)
    {
        this.client = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        } catch(IOException ignored) {
        }

        while (true) {
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                    out.println(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Read Failed");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TCP doesn't support broadcast, **but** you can simply send the same message to every client yourself.

Comment: How can that be done? Can we use arrayList?

Comment: You must maintain your own thread-safe list of connected clients, and then you can loop through that list whenever you need to send a broadcast message.  Just make sure your communication protocol is designed to support unsolicited messages being sent from server to client at any time, and that you perform each individual client send in a thread-safe manner to avoid overlapping messages sent by multiple threads at the same time.  Otherwise, you will very easily corrupt your communications. TCP broadcasting is not trivial to manage correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concurrent hashmap and maintain your list of clients in that.
The concurrent hashmap is safe and you won't need to use synchronization while adding / iterating / removing

```
// Create and main list of active clients based on their host name / ip address
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Socket> activeClients = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Socket>();

// message received
activeClients.put(clientsocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), clientsocket);

// broadcast message to all available clients
for(String clientHost : activeClients.keySet()) {
      // get each socket here and send a message to them.
}
```

Vector is basically a thread safe one so you don't need to worry about that one.

Comment: Right now i am trying to use **Vector** class but i need to do synchronisation there. Isn't this a good approach?